# Agregar el nombre del remitente a mi mensaje de email PHP mail()

Tags: php, mail

Tengo un formulario para enviarle mensajes de email a mis clientes, para ello uso la función `mail()` de PHP. Todo funciona a la perfección excepto por un detalle que no me gusta. Y es que al enviar el mensaje a mis clientes el nombre se muestra como mismo se llama el correo que estilizo yo para enviar el email, **noreply** y me gustaría que se llamara como mismo se llama mi sitio web.

[image: Mensaje de email]

Esta es la forma en como me llega mi mensaje, y me gustaría que en vez de decir **noreply**, dijera **The Canario**

### Para enviar el mensaje estoy usando este código

```
// Enviar el email
mail($email, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabecera, '-fnoreply@thecanario.com');
```

También por ultimo, me gustaría agregar una descripción a mi mensaje de email. Luego del asunto, se puede leer un texto que dice: *The canario favicon sitio web de historia*. Eso se debe a que esta leyendo el contenido el mensaje de email y a mi me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de agregar una descripción escrita por mi, que sea algo que yo escriba y no que lea automáticamente.

Espero que hayan logrado entender bien que es lo que yo quiero. De igual modo les agradeceré mucho si logran solucionar mi inconveniente. *!Gracias!*

Comment: ¿Leíste [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php)? Me parece que todo lo que quieres hacer está claramente explicado allí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la parte de `to` de la cabecera, escribirlo así:

```
// ...
$cabecera .= "From: $nombre_que_quieres_mostrar <$direccion_from>" . "\r\n";
// ...
```

Ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18870250/1545868) (en inglés)

Y para la parte de vista preliminar no creo que se pueda cambiar porque es una función del fabricante del cliente. Pero en el html del correo puedes eliminar esa línea de *favicon*, lo mismo con *title*, *meta*, *link*, *scripts*, etc ya que los correos no usan favicon ni linkean nada de su cabecera html.